# AWS cloudformation elasticsearch encryption at rest (KMS encryption)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

AWS ElasticSearch supports encryption at rest via console and API. The boto api seems to have a facility for enabling this and use a custom KMS key. I couldn't find a way to configure this using cloudformation template. Is it not supported yet or am I missing it?

ElasticSearch cloudformation documentation:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/encryption-at-rest-now-available-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Comment: They [just added](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) it for S3 and DynamoDB so ES might be around the corner.

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410014/aws-elasticsearch-service-set-encryption-options-from-cf-template/58593665#58593665 Templates included. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I learnt that the feature is not supported yet in cloudformation template. The console/APIs supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes As of today AWS CloudFormation doesn't support option to specify "Encryption at rest". besides its available with AWS CLI and aws sdks like java or boto3.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/es.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/es/create-elasticsearch-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

Found that we can use terraform to deploy aws resources with all the options needed (including encryption at rest). Below is documentation.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticsearch_domain.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Already added to CloudFormation  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-encryptionatrestoptions.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Supported now by Cloudformation :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html

if you are trying to enable fine grained access then you will need:
Advanced Security Options:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-advancedsecurityoptionsinput.html
Kms:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html
Node to node encryption:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-opensearchservice-domain-nodetonodeencryptionoptions.html